# Python - Write all tuples of a combination using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I would like to create all pairs `(i, j)` such that `i` goes from `0` to `n-1` and `j` goes from `i` to `n-1`. Basically these are all the unique combinations for two lists of length `n`.

As an example if `n=3` then I would like to get

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

It would be great if I could do this with a list comprehension. The long way around would be

```
n = 3
tuples = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
         tuples.append((i, j))
```

I have tried this list comprehension, unsuccessfully

```
tuples = [(i,j) for i in range(3) and j in range(i, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch the order of your loops:

```
tuples = [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(i, 3)]
```

Output:

```
Out[425]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```